# Many to Many JSON POST - Rails 5 - Only API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, restful, entidade-relacionamento

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma Engine no Rails 5 onde sera apenas uma API de blog. Será um sistema simples. Post tem várias Passions e Passions tem vários Posts. Fiz o relacionamento N <->

O Problema é que ao enviar o JSON do post com os IDs das Passions que quero associar a ele não consigo salva-las.

Post.rb

```
module Feed
  class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :post_passions,  dependent: :destroy 
    has_many :passions, :through => :post_passions
  end
end
```

Passion.rb

```
module Feed
  class Passion < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :post_passions
    has_many :post, :through => :post_passions
  end
end
```

PostPassion.rb (Join Table)

```
module Feed
  class PostPassion < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :passion
     belongs_to :post
  end
end
```

Meu objetivo é através de uma requisição POST na api '/feed/posts' consiga criar um post especificando varias Passions. O JSON estou enviando é o seguinte.

```
{
  "title": "Titulo da postagem",
  "description":"Decrição do post",
  "passion_ids":[1,2]
}
```

Enviando este post ao olhar o log do rails que recebe a requisição o atributo 'passion_ids' não é enviando dentro de post para que eu possa permiti-lo.

Log ao enviar a requisição

```
Started POST "/feed/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-29 08:20:00 -0300
Processing by Feed::PostsController#create as */*
Parameters: {"title"=>"Titulo da postagem", "description"=>"Decrição do post", "passion_ids"=>[1, 2], "post"=>{"title"=>"Titulo da postagem", "description"=>"Decrição do post"}}
```

Como o 'passion_ids'não é recebido dentro de Post o permit abaixo não funciona.

```
params.require(:post).permit(:title,
                             :passion_ids,
                             :description)
```

Tenho um sistema que funciona dessa forma porem é em rails 4.2 e os cadastros são feitos por formulários e não por REST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que tem algumas questões ai. Em primeiro, acho que sua requisição JSON deveria ter um root, no caso:

```
{
    "post": {
        "title": "Titulo da postagem",
        "description":"Decrição do post",
        "passion_ids":[1,2]
    }
}
```

Em segundo, se vocẽ quer passar um array como parâmetro, você deve permitir ele de maneira diferente, assim:

```
params.require(:post).permit(:title,
                             :description,
                             passion_ids: [])
```

Assim o rails sabe que você vai passar um array. Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o erro esteja aqui

`params.require(:post).permit(:title,:passion_ids,:description)`

o teu ':passion_ids' está como atributo de :post, enquanto ele está sendo passado na raiz dos parâmetros pelo requisição.

Comment: Então, mas para que eu consiga cadastrar as Passions junto com o Post estes dados deveriam vir juntos com Post. Eles vindo juntos quando fizer post = Post.new(params_post) / post.save() eu já salvaria eles com todas as Passions setadas.

Answer (score 0):

Pra receber o `passion_ids` precisa ter este atributo `passion_ids` em `model.post`

`params.require(:post).permit(:title, :passion_ids, :description)`